# Backtracking with the awk (GNU) command

Tags: bash, awk

Say one of your data files returns you all their readings. After removing all the clutter; you obtain, with always 3 columns:

```
-ERROR -1.57 -2.02 
-2.10 -0.57 ERROR
-4.70 ERROR -0.52 
-2.20 ERROR -0.02 
-2.20 -0.07 ERROR
```

I know `ERROR` is **the only error message** and happens for any data at random, and is, therefore, the only value that isn't a number.

**THE CHALLENGE**

How can I replace any invalid reading with the last successful one? I've tried

```
awk -F' ' ' {if (isNumber $1){ replace with previous $1}}' < log.data
```

But how do you reference the previous reading to begin with?

Expected output:

```
 0 -1.57 -2.02 
-2.10 -0.57 -2.02
-4.70 -0.57 -0.52 
-2.20 -0.57 -0.02 
-2.20 -0.07 -0.02
```

Comment: What is your expected output for shown input?

Comment: Save `$1` in a variable. Then use that in the replacement

Comment: @anubhava I've added an expected output. The 0 comes from a temp variable that was initialized at 0.

Comment: will you always be dealing with 3 fields/columns or could it be variable? a

Comment: @markp-fuso That is because it is an error message, I suppose I could replace all the messages to be the same with sed 's/IMPOSSIBLE ALT/ERROR/g'. So they all have 3 columns. I'll update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all rows have the same number of space-delimted fields/columns
- all non-numeric values contain the literal string `ERROR`
- if first row contains a non-numeric value then the replacement value will be zero (0)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {     # loop through fields
      if ($i ~ "ERROR")     # if problematic value found then ...
         $i=last[i]+0       # replace with the last value seen; "+0" to force undefined to be zero (and not "")
      last[i]=$i            # save current field as "last" for the next input line
  }
  print $0                  # print current line
}
' log.data
```

This generates:

```
0 -1.57 -2.02
-2.10 -0.57 -2.02
-4.70 -0.57 -0.52
-2.20 -0.57 -0.02
-2.20 -0.07 -0.02
```

Comment: While `$i ~ "ERROR"` will behave as desired given the posted sample input, it has a couple of peculiarities since `~` is the regexp comparison operator but you're using it to compare against text within string instead of regexp delimiters. It should either be written as a regexp comparison (`~`) against a regexp (`/.../`), i.e. `$i ~ /ERROR/` or (which seems to be more accurate in this case) a string comparison (`==`) against a string (`"..."`), i.e. `$i == "ERROR"` rather than a mixture of both regexp and string constructs.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
      if ($i+0 != $i)
         $i = prev[i]+0
      prev[i]=$i
   }
} 1' file

0 -1.57 -2.02
-2.10 -0.57 -2.02
-4.70 -0.57 -0.52
-2.20 -0.57 -0.02
-2.20 -0.07 -0.02
```

`$i+0 != $i` will return true if `$i` is non-numeric value.

Comment: I did not know of the $i+0 != $i syntax, quite clever actually.

Comment: It is very handy if you want to handle all the non-numeric values not just single `ERROR`.